# How to retrieve an object by ID entity Framework?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, repository-pattern, autofac

I followed up this tutorial  [here](http://michaelfarag.blogspot.co.uk/2013/10/step-by-step-guide-mvc-4-entity.html) To implement Repository pattern with Autofac dependency injector and Unit Of Work.

Now I am trying to retrieve an artist Object from database.

With Dbcontext it was as easy as just using `_db.Artists.Find(id)` 
Now because I implemented Generic Repository also new Repository patern. I am not sure what should be  the query

in my artist controller

```
 return View(this._artistDetailsRep.SingleOrDefault(p => p.ArtistID= id));
```

which complains that  an experssion tree cannot an assignment operator.

here is the generic method :

```
 public virtual TEntity SingleOrDefault(
        Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> where, params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] includeProperties)
    {
        IQueryable<TEntity> query = this.AsQueryable();
        query = PerformInclusions(includeProperties, query);
        return query.SingleOrDefault(where);
    }
```

How should be my query to retrieve the object that I knot the id of it?

Thanks

Comment: You need to write: `return View(this._artistDetailsRep.SingleOrDefault(p => p.ArtistID == id));` so double `==` instead of a single `=`

Comment: U should take a break :) Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Your issue is not related to EF or Autofac or to the repository pattern but you are misusing the `SingleOrDefault`: you need to use double equals `==` instead of a single equals sign `=`:

```
return View(this._artistDetailsRep.SingleOrDefault(p => p.ArtistID == id));
```

An single equals sign `=` means assignment (which is invalid in this context) but in your case you need comparasion so you need double equals `==`.

In this case your `SingleOrDefault` call will translates to: "give me the only artist with the `ArtistID` equals `id` or `null` if the artist does not exists."